# Htaccess redirect all /home?page=x to /home where x can be any number

Tags: .htaccess

Could any of you help me with a redirect. I have lot of links like these:

```
https://www.mywebsite/home?page=x where x can be any number

https://www.mywebsite/home
```

How can I do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)page=\d+(?:$|&) [NC]
RewriteRule ^home$ home? [NC,R=302,L]
```

If you are using a recent version of Apache, use for the last line:

```
RewriteRule ^home$ home [NC,QSD,R=302,L]
```